# Convert from length in mm to feet and inces and back to mm

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a small Problem with convert a lenght into feet and inches.

My code:

```
 // input data
 this.data = 2500;

 //get feet
 this.feet = Math.floor(this.data / 304.8);

 //get inches
 let feetrestinmm = this.data - this.feet * 304.8;
 this.inches = Math.floor(feetrestinmm / 25.4);

 //get fraction inches
 let inchesrestinmm = feetrestinmm - this.inches * 25.4;
 this.toFraction(inchesrestinmm / 25.4);

 //back to mm
 this.mmValueOut = this.fractionToNumber(this.inchesFraction1 + '/' + this.inchesFraction2) + (this.inches * 25.4) + (this.feet * 304.8);
```

```
toFraction(x: number)
  {
    let tolerance = 1.0E-6;
    let h1 = 1;
    let h2 = 0;
    let k1 = 0;
    let k2 = 1;
    let b = x;
    do {
      let a = Math.floor(b);
      let aux = h1;
      h1 = a * h1 + h2;
      h2 = aux;
      aux = k1;
      k1 = a * k1 + k2;
      k2 = aux;
      b = 1 / (b - a);
    } while (Math.abs(x - h1 / k1) > x * tolerance);

    this.inchesFraction1 = h1;
    this.inchesFraction2 = k1;
  }

  fractionToNumber(fraction: string) {
    let numbers = fraction.split('/');
    return Number.parseFloat(numbers[0]) / Number.parseFloat(numbers[1]);
  }
```

so the result i get of 2500mm are 8 feet, 2 inches and 54/127.
But the fraction are very strange. in a [onlineconverter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/length/mm-to-inch.html) i get 27/64 for the fraction. 
If i calculate back to mm, i get less than input value.

Can somone tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: 27 + 27 = 54 ---- 64 + 64 = 128. The fraction you get is simply the not-yet reduced version of the online one (minus some mistake you might have made about the calculations - for instance, `Math.floor`).

Comment: Probably angular or the online converter are rounding the result

Answer (score 0):

@Maryannah is right. To get the correct value you should use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor` and reduce the return value of your `toFraction` function with something like this:

```
function ggT(a, b) {
  var c, d;
  c = a; d = b;
  while ( c != d ) {
    if ( c < d )
      d = d - c
    else c = c - d
  }
  return(c);
```

So your `toFraction` would be:

```
toFraction(x: number)
  {
    let tolerance = 1.0E-6;
    let h1 = 1;
    let h2 = 0;
    let k1 = 0;
    let k2 = 1;
    let b = x;
    do {
      let a = Math.floor(b);
      let aux = h1;
      h1 = a * h1 + h2;
      h2 = aux;
      aux = k1;
      k1 = a * k1 + k2;
      k2 = aux;
      b = 1 / (b - a);
    } while (Math.abs(x - h1 / k1) > x * tolerance);

    let reducer = ggT(h1,k1)

    this.inchesFraction1 = (h1/reducer);
    this.inchesFraction2 = (k1/reducer);
  }
```

Comment: hmm. thanks but i get the same result as with Math.floor and witheout reduce :-(